# Spring Boot 2 & Spring 5 Container confusion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have a Spring boot 1.4.3 project. Recently I have come up with a requirement where I have to send logs from server to my web application and print the logs on the web page. I am aware of WebSockets but I was looking for better solutions and I came across, Reactive Programming and gRPC.

Spring is supporting Reactive Programming in Spring version 5, but I am quite confused between gRPC and Reactive Programming. gRPC features Bi-Directional streaming which is built on top of Netty and provides the same facility as pushing data from the server to clients like Reactive Programming. So which one should I use, If you can clear me on this confusion it would be really great.

Also, If I move to Spring Boot 2 which supports Spring Version 5, the project will be running on Netty. My confusion is, do I have to run my application on different containers like for normal REST endpoints on Jetty server and for Reactive API on netty server or Spring will handle this for me out of the box by handling reactive requests on netty and remaining general REST API on the jetty server, because as far as I know Netty is not a Servlet Container.

Comment: Why would reactive programming solve this? Only reactive programming doesn't add anything. Also Spring Boot 2 nor Spring 5 are final yet so you probably don't want to use that in production. If you only want to send logs, store them somewhere where you can access them (like the database) instead of trying to rewrite your whole application.

Comment: @M.Deinum Data for logs are stored in a database but the frontend will be connected to the backend so that the logs can be read from the database and will be pushed to the frontend as a continues stream of data. Continuously updated logs data will also be read and pushed to the client during the same active connection.

Comment: Still reactive won't help you with that. You still need a mechanism to transport it to the front end like either Server Sent Events of Web Sockets. Both of which you can do perfectly well without reactive programming.

Comment: @M.Deinum As I said, while looking at reactive programming I came to know that data can be pushed from server to client as a continuous stream of data in reactive programming and the same can be achieved through gRPC also(better than web sockets). Now, I am confused should I use gRPC or go with Reactive Programming.

Comment: Again only reactive programming without a means of transport will give you nothing. You still need a mechanism like gRPC (which as Andy points out isn't through gRPC), Web Sockets or Server Sent Events. Only slapping reactive programming on there isn't going to help you with that. Imho just implement it with Server Sent Evens in the stack you have now instead of trying to reintroduce a complete new stack for such a requirement.

Answer (score 7):

One key feature of reactive programming is back pressure, and back pressure that's implemented in a non-blocking manner. At the time of writing, gRPC [doesn't support this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9494).

There's also much more to reactive programming than the communication between a client and a server. To be truly reactive, you need to be reactive from end to end. This includes reactive access to your data store, etc. As far as I know, this isn't something that's tackled by gRPC.

You shouldn't try to mix the use of a traditional Servlet-based web framework (such as Spring MVC) with use of WebFlux (Spring's reactive web framework). You should either write a 100% reactive web application or a 100% Servlet-based web application.