# Fabric8 kubernetes API Handshake error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, fabric8

I am using kubernetes-client from inside a Docker container and it is giving me the below error while connecting to the Kubernetes master.

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config : Error reading service account token 
from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token].
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target at 
sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils$2.intercept(HttpClientUtils.java:90) ~[kubernetes-client-3.0.3.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135) ~[okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) [okhttp-3.8.1.jar!/:na] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121] Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496) ~[na:1.8.0_121] ... 33 common frames omitted Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_121] at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

When I try to connect to Google Kubernetes Engine from the local computer it is successful, however, when I try to do the same from a Docker container running on Google Compute Engine it is giving the above error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It looks like in your [past question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404379/spring-boot-2-spring-5-container-confusion), you have not replied to an answer, and of your 13 questions, you've not accepted a single one. This may not encourage folks to help you with your new questions.